# O que é RecyclerView em Android?

Tags: java, android, view

Qual é a função do `RecyclerView` em uma aplicação Android?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`RecyclerView` veio para substituir tanto o `ListView` quanto o `GridView` (incluindo as entidades de apoio a ambas).

O `RecyclerView` é muito mais eficiente que as duas antigas implementações, mesmo utilizando uma configuração de `ViewHolder` praticamente igual (não podemos definir otimização apenas no aspecto do `ViewHolder`). Uma das grandes de suas grandes vantagens, é a flexibilidade de poder mudar de `LayoutManager` sem ter de implementar um caminhão de código somente para ter versões de tiles ou cards em nossa lista.

Como com `ListView` e `GridView`, o `RecyclerView` precisa de entidades extras para poder funcionar, no caso temos o `LayoutManager` (no vídeo utilizei o `LinearLayoutManager`) que é responsável pela redenrização da `View` de cada item no screen do device.

Temos o `Adapter` que é reponsável por vincular os dados do conjunto passado a ele a `View` (que será a view de cada item do `RecyclerView`) e então enviar essa `View` ao `LayoutManager`.

E, para finalizar, temos o `ViewHolder` que é responsável pela cache das `View`'s criadas no método `onCreateViewHolder()` para posteriormente reutiliza-las otimizando então o trabalho com o `RecyclerView`.

Video: http://www.thiengo.com.br/recyclerview-material-design-android-parte-2

Comment: Vou editar a resposta Holmes.

Comment: Esse material é desse link que coloquei na resposta, obrigado.