# Como exibir uma lista de resultados em uma activity?

Tags: php, android, json, intent, bundle

Tenho um conhecimento bastante limitado em programação e estou começando Android agora. Comecei a desenvolver um projeto em Android para fisioterapia.

Nesse projeto os fisioterapeutas poderão se cadastrar e fazer o login para editar, exibir e cadastrar os dados dos pacientes, entre outras coisas. 
Estou utilizando o PHP, MySQL e Android para fazer todo esse processo. Por enquanto, consegui fazer a comunicação entre o Android e o PHP para troca de objetos Json.

O meu problema é: quando o fisioterapeuta faz o login, deve-se exibir EM OUTRA TELA os pacientes que foram cadastrados por ele. O problema é que o Android está diretamente atrelado ao XML e eu não sei como vou adicionar esses pacientes de forma proporcional ao que consta no banco de dados. Pode ter 1,2,3,30,40, etc.

Alguém poderia me dar uma luz para eu saber de que forma eu posso exibir esses dados e se posso criar botões para editar e deletar esses pacientes (atrelado ao nome deles)? Eu já pesquisei bastante mas o máximo que encontrei foi a exibição de dados de forma estática, sem interação.

Comment: Essa pergunta não tem uma resposta trivial. Você deve dar uma estudada em RecyclerView, Custom Adapter, ContentProvider, etc., pois não é uma resposta curta. Sugiro que dê uma olhada nesse curso: https://br.udacity.com/course/android-basics-data-storage--ud845/

Comment: Obrigado, consegui ao menos uma luz pois estava perdido.

Answer (score 1):

Nesse caso você tem que usar um dos componentes de listas no Android.

Existe o ListView, mais simples porém ficou obsoleto com a chegada do RecyclerView.

Estes dois componentes são utilizados para listas de repetição. Deixo como referência: [O que é RecyclerView em Android?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/82322/o-que-%C3%A9-recyclerview-em-android)

E tem o próprio tutorial do Google que ensina usar: https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html

Comment: Obrigado, ao menos consegui achar um caminho pois estava perdido.